# How to conditionally initialize component based on state?

Tags: reactjs

I've just started using React. I've written this simple component:

```
class DocVerDate extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        dateTypes: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(...arguments);
        this.state = {
            typeSelected: false
        };
    }

    typeChanged = ev => {
        this.setState({typeSelected: ev.target.value.length > 0});
    };

    render() {
        return <div className="cr-input-row">
            <select style={{width:'75px'}} className="_sent_select" onChange={this.typeChanged}>
                <option value="">(Sent)</option>
                {this.props.dateTypes.map(dt =>
                    <option key={dt[0]} value={dt[0]}>{dt[1]}</option>
                )}
            </select>
            { this.state.typeSelected ? [' on ', <input ref="datepicker" type="hidden"/>] : null }
        </div>
    }
}
```

Basically, depending on what you select from a dropdown select, a date field will appear.

I believe I can initialize that date widge via `$(this.refs.datepicker).datepicker()`, but the problem is that that element may or may not be in the DOM depending on the state.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap datepicker in a React component, so you'll have

```
{ this.state.typeSelected ? [' on ', <MyDatePicker />] : null }
```

And then in MyDatePicker you'll have

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.initializeDatePicker()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When something depend on state, you should do it on `componentDidUpdate`. Then check for the visibility of DatePicker, initialize it if it is currently visible and hasn't initialized yet.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    var $datePicker = $(this.refs.datepicker);
    if ($datePicker.length > 0 && DATE_PICKER_IS_NOT_INITIALIZED_YET) $datePicker.datepicker();
}
```

Comment: Now I know why that methods exists :) Thanks!